# Background screen visibility

Tags: android, android-recents, recent-screens

When going background, App's last accessed screen is not showing. Instead its showing blank screen shown in attached image..[image]

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_nico</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_nico</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/create</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DefaultTextView</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is your app activity fully loaded before putting your app in the background?

Comment: yup @Sam.......

Comment: Do you set any window flag in your activity?

Comment: Do you use transparent colors?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman : No I havent added any flag to secure.

Comment: @Eren Tüfekçi : Nope

Comment: @Richa I am not sure, in my case, it was because activity was not fully loaded and too many UI task on the main thread. Do check this post: https://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/